# How to Configure AucTeX to Preview .pdf File Generated by XeLaTeX?

Tags: latex, auctex

How can I achieve this by adding something to ~/.emacs

[This is my .emacs](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3hg7kYX4ph/)

OS: Ubuntu20.04LTS (WSL)

Emacs: 26.3

XeLaTeX: 6.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is covered in the [AucTeX manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Starting-Viewers.html), specifically the section `(auctex) Starting Viewers`.

The command to launch a viewer is:

> -- Command: TeX-view
> ('C-c C-v') Start a viewer without confirmation.  The viewer is
> started either on a region or the master file, depending on the
> last command issued.  This is especially useful for jumping to the
> location corresponding to point in the viewer when using
> 'TeX-source-correlate-mode'.

If you want to customize the program used to view pdfs, the variable to start with is `TeX-view-program-selection`:

> The association between the tests for the conditions mentioned above
> and the viewers is made in the variable 'TeX-view-program-selection'.
> Therefore this variable is the starting point for customization if you
> want to use other viewers than the ones suggested by default.
>
> -- User Option: TeX-view-program-selection
> This is a list of predicates and viewers which is evaluated from
> front to back in order to find out which viewer to call under the
> given conditions.  In the first element of each list item you can
> reference one or more predicates defined in
> 'TeX-view-predicate-list' or 'TeX-view-predicate-list-builtin'.  In
> the second element you can reference a viewer defined in
> 'TeX-view-program-list' or 'TeX-view-program-list-builtin'.  The
> viewer of the first item with a positively evaluated predicate is
> selected.

Check the manual for further details. If you still have specific questions after that, please come back and ask again!